# jquery multiple row selection

Tags: jquery, object, mouse, selection

Is it possible to select objects with jquery the same way you select files on windows/mac? I mean drag the mouse and whatever is under the created rectangle gets selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible as it is mentioned you can use JqueryUi functionality
Check also a simple example using core functionality

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yodero/rPb7v/15/light/)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQueryUI library together with jQuery to do what you want - see http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ and http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

There may be other jQuery plugins that can give you similar behavior to this as well, but I recommend jQueryUI as it would likely be maintained the best.

Also, be warned that it's not dead simple to do - this does require a good understanding of jQuery and javascript in general.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest "selectable" of jQueryUI.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, [have a look at this example](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/drag-to-select/)